# Page Transformation animation using nineoldandroid doesn't render on api level 10

Tags: android, android-viewpager, nineoldandroids, android-pagetransformer

I have following code for page transformation in  View Pager. It works well on api level 11 or above but not showing animation on api level 10 or below. Note that code uses NineOldAndroid lib to do all animations.

```
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper;

public class ZoomOutPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    private static float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;
    private static float MIN_ALPHA = 0.5f;

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
        int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, 0);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
            // Modify the default slide transition to shrink the page as well
            float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
            float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            if (position < 0) {
                ViewHelper.setTranslationX(view, (horzMargin - vertMargin / 2));
            } else {
                ViewHelper.setTranslationX(view, -horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
            }

            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            ViewHelper.setScaleX(view, scaleFactor);
            ViewHelper.setScaleY(view, scaleFactor);

            // Fade the page relative to its size.
            ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, MIN_ALPHA +
                    (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) /
                            (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, 0);
        }
    }

}
```